# yarn 3 install provides empty node_modules + npx scripts failures

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, npx, yarnpkg-v2

I'm migrating my node repositories to yarn berry (v3) from yarn 1. So had a basic old school package.json and yarn.lock. And only a .yarnrc file to host npmjs token at user home folder. Nothing complicated.

Everything works well with all deps and devDeps on github actions, on my previous computer (yarn v1), on my intern computer (yarn v1 too), ...

When running yarn v3 for first time, told me that it migrates everything automatically to the new way (great news!).

So done a basic `yarn install` and seems that goes well
[image]

`yarn.lock` file is updated to new style with all deps

But now node_modules is empty. There are some `npx scripts` which are not able to run because node_modules is still empty (even if running with yarn instead of npx).

Here is my `yarnrc.yml` file

```
defaultSemverRangePrefix: ""

plugins:
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-interactive-tools.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-interactive-tools"
```

First lines of `yarn.lock`

[image]

What i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to my `.yarnrc.yml` file

```
nmMode: classic
nodeLinker: node-modules
```

Solved the problem. Yarn 3 berry put all modules into `.yarn/cache` folder instead of `node_modules` old school way. I need to still use this folder.